# Drag a div out the box.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag, bounce

I have make a div in the right of the screen. First you have a a href. You can drag this div open with this button. Here is a example: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ErWjr/) Right in the screen you see the "Wat is een delicous tasting" button. You can drag it open.

But i have problems with this. This are the problems:

- The biggest problem. When you drag the div open. And than you drag the div back. You can drag the div outside the screen. But the is not good. When you closed the div. You can not drag it out the screen.
- How can i fadein the overlay. The overlay must be smooth. Now it is not pretty.
- How can i make a bounce effect in the box.

I am an beginning javascripter. I hope you can help me with this!! Thanks for helping!

You can change the code on jsFiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErWjr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition test to check whether the mouse position exceeds a certain boundary or not. If the mouse go past a fixed limit (`window width - element's width`), don't change the `right` attribute of the marker.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ErWjr/1/**

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var box = $(".what-is-delicious"),
        button = $(".what-is-delicious > a"),
        mouseDown = false,
        grabbed   = 0,
        start     = -303,
        maxLeftOffset = $(window).width() - 75;
        // ^^^ Limit to 75px from the right (= marker's width)
    button.mousedown(function (e) {
        mouseDown = true;
        $('*').bind('selectstart', false);
        grabbed = e.pageX;
        button.css({ cursor: "-moz-grabbing"});
        $("body").append('<div class="background-overlay"></div>');
    });
    $('body').mouseup(function () {
        mouseDown = false;
        $('*').unbind('selectstart', false);
        button.css({ cursor: "-moz-grab"});
        $(".background-overlay").remove();
        start = parseInt(box.css('right'), 10);
    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (mouseDown) {
            if(e.pageX > maxLeftOffset) return; //<---- Don't go past an edge
            //button.addClass("open");
            box.css("right", Math.min(grabbed - e.pageX + start, 0));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you are trying to emulate dragging rather than using the plugin designed for the purpose. Try this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

There are a bunch of demos there, one of those should sort you out.